Why converge in measure does not imply converge almost everywhere?
I know that in general converge in measure does not imply converge almost everywhere and I know a  counter example. But one of the proposition says that if $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure, then there is a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere. So what is wrong with the following "proof":
$\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure
$\Leftrightarrow$ every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converges to $f$ in measure
$\Rightarrow$ every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ has a subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere
$\Leftrightarrow$ $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere

The last $\Leftrightarrow$ is false.

The last implication is true for constant functions but not for general measurable functions.

This argument shows that the convergence almost everywhere is non-topological (i.e. it cannot be described as the convergence induced by some topology on the set of your measurable functions).
The last equivalence that you wrote (A sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges in some sense if and only if every subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ has another subsequence which converges to the same limit $f$ in that sense) is only true if you can describe your convergence by a topology.
Think about the proofs of this characterisation: Depending on your context (topological, metric, normed space) you would for the sake of a contradiction assume that $(f_n)_n$ does not converge. Then you would find a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and for any $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n_k \ge n$ such that $f_{n_k} \notin U$. But then, no subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ would converge to $f$, since none of the elements of this subsequence are in $U$. Of course in a normed or metric space, this proof can be carried out with $\epsilon$-balls instead of general neighbourhoods.
But in any case: You need to be able to describe the convergence by a topology.
Now the way to think about the seemingliy contradicting situation is the following: since there are examples of sequences which converge in measure but not pointwise a.e., you know that your "proof" has to be wrong and this implies that the convergence a.e. is non-topological because the other equivalences and implications you wrote are correct.
